# How to clear all the widgets except labels

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, pyqt4

H,

I have a frame and in side frame there are many widgets as shown.

[image]

Widgets can be clear in a frame using the following code

```
for widget in parent_widget.findChildren(QWidget):
    if hasattr(widget, "clear") and callable(widget.clear):
        widget.clear()
```

but this even deletes lables.

[image]

How to clear all elements like combobox and lineedit but leaving lables as it is?

Comment: Can't you add an extra condition like `not isinstance(widget, QLabel)` to your if-statement?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Heike for the answer

this solution worked like charm

```
if not isinstance(widget, QLabel) and hasattr(widget, "clear") and callable(widget.clear):
    widget.clear()
```